# How to get the bits of a hexadecimal number AES implementation

Tags: c, encryption, binary, hex, bit

i have a sbox for an AES type implementation like

```
int   box[4][4] = {{0xA,0x3,0xC,0xB},
            {0xE,0xF,0x2,0xE},
            {0x6,0x4,0x0,0xF},
            {0xC,0x4,0xF,0x3}};
```

i want to get the first 2 bits and last 2 bits of a hexadecimal number and then replace it with the position in the sbox for example

```
  int x = 0xA //Because A has a binary representation from hex as 1010
```

then the row number would become the first 2 bits of A "10" and the column number would become the second 2 bits of A "10" therefore int x would go to the sbox and be replaced with "0xF"

how could i get the bits of A and use it to look up my sbox ?

Comment: Why replaced with `0xF` when there's a `0x0` at that position?

Comment: o i have the starting from position 0 thats why so the sbox has columns 0 1 2 3 and rows 0 1 2 3 

but anyways 0x0 or 0xF do u know how to retrieve the bits of a position specified and access the sbox

Comment: You have to remember that hexadecimal is just a *presentational* feature. It's all stored in binary inside the computer anyway. Also, you want the (total) four bits of the *lowest nibble*, you can't forget that `int` is usually 32 bits which means that saying "highest two bits" means something else.

Comment: `box[x&3][(x>>2)&3]`?

Comment: also Joachim Pileborg yes i am having a hard time always remembering that the hexidecimal in c is simply a view and it is still represented as a binary also yes i am aware that there is usually 32 bits this is my problem i just want the lowest 4 bits and i want to split them in 2 and use them to look up my sbox

Thank you for putting up with my inexperience all help is welcome !

Comment: Joachim Isaksson

Worked Brilliantly thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x = box[x & 3][(x >> 2) & 3];` will work assuming when you said "the row number would become the first 2 bits" you meant the two lower order bits of the four [i.e., the right two]; otherwise (when you said "first 2" you meant "left 2"), `x = box[(x >> 2) & 3][x & 3];` is what you need.

In general, however, your 2 dimensional array accesses are slower than a 1 dimensional array access, so I would use a 1D array instead and not isolate the two pairs of bits as separate indexes.  Instead use the low 4 bits of x as a 1D index.  Then there won't be any extra shifting and masking or multiplication and addition of the 2D offset address calculation.

If "first 2 bits" meant "rightmost 2 bits"...

```
int box[16] = {0xA,0xE,0x6,0xC, 0x3,0xF,0x4,0x4, 0xC,0x2,0x0,0xF, 0xB,0xE,0xF,0x3};
```

If "first 2 bits" meant "leftmost 2 bits"...

```
int box[16] = {0xA,0x3,0xC,0xB, 0xE,0xF,0x2,0xE, 0x6,0x4,0x0,0xF, 0xC,0x4,0xF,0x3};
```

Then, to use the box...

```
x = box[x & 0xF];  // use the bottom 4 bits as single index
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Just an additional note... the last line of code, `x = box[x & 0xF];`, uses the `0xF` mask, which is easy enough to understand, but you still have to think through these raw hex masks to determine what bits will be 1 or 0.  You can also generates this mask at compile time (no effect on speed) like so... `#define MASK (~(~0 << 4) << 0)`.  ~0 (invert of 0) is all 1s.  ~0 << 4 is all 1s with 4 0s on the right.  Invert and you get all 0s with 4 1s on the right.  Left shift 0 starts the low end of the 4 1s at bit 0.  Change the last 0 to 12, and the 4 1s would start at bit 12.